# How to encrypt plain text facebook password into the encrypted format before it is sent ? (#PWD_BROWSER)

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, python-requests, passwords

Facebook encrypts plain text password before sending it as a login request to the server

eg when I login with random login credentials:

This is the post request body sent , the email used is test12345@gmail.com and the password was test12345

```
email: test12345@gmail.com

login_source: comet_headerless_login

encpass: #PWD_BROWSER:5:1683905042:AcZQAJrk/vksWHThqOkelJMFc6UCV35HSZY5kIlN8qfRPxxMAtKIaV0h+e5ACcb8PXPqTx3m5D+lOp+ylB+CY6WMmsyIwrx5sxBvurrCtQX3Re+aGM/VfITIVk9HnQMkvlx9ZMJJjF2zW6Ym5g==
```

*above, my password (test12345) was encypted into that encpass*

And I don't know which encrypted method they used , but I know that #PWD_BROWSER and the 5 after it do not change , and the next numbers (1683905042) is time stamp , but the encryption after that I can't figure it out

I inspected the facebook page source and saw the function that encodes the password  before sending , but even that us not quite clear , here it is:

```
_encryptBeforeSending: function(a) {
            a = a.bind(h);
            var d = h.loginFormParams && h.loginFormParams.pubKey;
            if ((window.crypto || window.msCrypto) && d) {
                var e = c("DOM").scry(h.loginForm, 'input[id="pass"]')[0],
                    f = b("FBBrowserPasswordEncryption"),
                    g = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1e3).toString();
                c("promiseDone")(f.encryptPassword(d.keyId, d.publicKey, e.value, g), function(b) {
                    b = c("DOM").create("input", {
                        type: "hidden",
                        name: "encpass",
                        value: b
                    });
                    h.loginForm.appendChild(b);
                    e.disabled = !0;
                    a()
                }, function(c) {
                    var d = "#PWD_BROWSER",
                        e = 5,
                        f = b("LoginServicePasswordEncryptDecryptEventTypedLogger");
                    new f().setError("BrowserEncryptionFailureInLoginFormControllerWWW").setGrowthFlow("Bluebar/main login WWW").setErrorMessage(c.message).setPasswordTag(d).setPasswordEncryptionVersion(e).setPasswordTimestamp(g).logVital();
                    a()
                })
            } else a()
        },
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to login programmatically. They have an API you have to use.